# Jeep Cherokee Torque/Reaction arm

Tags: suspension, jeep, cherokee, control-arm

i have a Jeep Cherokee Limited 2.8CRD (06 plate) which has just failed its MOT.

the "Torque/Reaction arm" to both nearside and offside rear need replacing.

what is this?

is it the same thing as "control arm"?

Ade